# How to restore deleted 'node_modules' folder?

Tags: npm

On Ubuntu 16.04 I accidently deleted the 'node_modules' folder so that I can't run `npm` anymore. I get the error:

`bash: /usr/local/bin/npm: No such file or directory`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you deleted more than your `node_modules` directory, if the `npm` binary is missing. Just [Reinstall Node.js/npm](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-16-04).

Answer (score 12):

If `package.json` is present in your project directory, which usually is, then run `npm install` and all the packages will be restored as well as the `node_modules` directory, where they are stored.

Answer (score 0):

just type npm i in your project and nodemodule will install .